# Confused about the cost of SQL in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

```
Select pn.pn_level_id From phone_number pn Where pn.phone_number='15183773646'


Select pn.pn_level_id From phone_number pn Where pn.phone_number=' 15183773646'
```

**Do you think they are the same ? No. Basically they are not the same in the PL/SQL Devloper.**

[image]
[image]

I'm wondering why the latter one's cost is less than the previous sql.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @zaratustra Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Does you database have the `pn.phone_number=' 15183773646'`?

Comment: @zaratustra Actually there is no number like that.

Comment: Took me ages to find that extra space in the phone number string.

Comment: @Rene ages...It's really a long time.

Comment: @Brutal Could have taken me forever, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer evaluates all the ways to extract data, since you database doesn't have the `pn.phone_number=' 15183773646'` and this value is not stored in the index hence Oracle skip one I/O operation this is why the second cost is less.

Answer (score 1):

The cost is not the same because when cost is calculated planner takes into account available statistics. Statistics among other things contains values which appear most frequently in column with their frequencies. It allows planner to better estimate number of rows which will be fetched and to decide how to better get data (e.g. via sequential scan or by index).

In your case value 15183773646 is probably among mostly frequently appearing and that's why planner estimation is different for the query involving it (as planner has better estimation of number of such rows) as compared to other values for which it basically guesses.